# Remember CSS stylesheet change when templates are rendered in flask

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2

I have build a flask application with HTML and **external (static) CSS stylesheets**. The application has a checkbox, **the checkbox controls which CSS stylesheet is active with JavaScript**. The purpose of the 2 different external stylesheets is to allow to user to switch between a light- (base) and a dark mode.

The above functionality is working as expected. However when a new template is rendered, the base.html file which contains the **intiial CSS stylesheet** in the `<header>` is loaded.

How can I keep the change in CSS stylesheets when a new template is rendered in flask?

**Example**

For every html page that is rendered, the `base.html` is extended. This file contains the `base-theme.css` file as the intial CSS stylesheet.

`base.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Application Name</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Application Name">
    <link rel="favorite icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/base-theme.css') }}" id="stylesheet_toggle">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/switch_mode.js') }}"></script>
</head>

<body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

When the checkbox (`topnav_right_mode_toggle`) is checked, the CSS stylesheet is changed from the `base-theme.css` to the `dark-theme.css` with JavaScript:

`switch_mode.js`

```
window.onload = function () {
    const toggle = document.getElementById("topnav_right_mode_toggle");
    const theme = document.getElementById("stylesheet_toggle");

    toggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (theme.getAttribute("href") == "/static/css/base-theme.css") {
            theme.href = "/static/css/dark-theme.css";
        } else {
            theme.href = "/static/css/base-theme.css";
        }
    });
}
```

**So far, so good...**

Now another endpoint is triggered and for this endpoint another html file is rendered. This html file extends the `base.html` and because the `base.html` contains the CSS stylesheet: `base-theme.css`, the change to the stylesheet: `dark-theme.css` is undone.

How can I remember the change to the stylesheet when another html file is rendered?

Comment: Please let me know if the question is unclear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need to do is *store* this information so that it persists between requests to the server & therefore across the different pages of your app.

One neat solution is to use the browser's [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

You could just store the selected theme's location in `localStorage` and retrieve on each page load, e.g.

```
window.onload = function () {
    const toggle = document.getElementById("topnav_right_mode_toggle");
    const theme = document.getElementById("stylesheet_toggle");
    const selected = localStorage.getItem("css");
    if (selected !== null) {
      theme.href = selected;
    }

    toggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (theme.getAttribute("href") == "/static/css/base-theme.css") {
            theme.href = "/static/css/dark-theme.css";
        } else {
            theme.href = "/static/css/base-theme.css";
        }
        localStorage.setItem("css", theme.href);
    });
}
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks a lot! I could not find any (acceptable) solution in the past couple of days.

Comment: You say: "One neat solution is..", can I ask you if you think there is a solution to achieve this without the use of JS? If possible, I would like to finish this application wihout using JS. Noting against JS but it's better for this use case. Do you think it's possible to achive a light-/dark theme (in flask) without using JS (i.e. HTML and CSS only)?

Comment: Since your initial code used JavaScript, I offered what is probably the simplest and cleanest JS solution. In general, this information is best managed by the frontend, rather than the backend.

Comment: A purely Python (backend) solution *is* possible - but it will be quite messy in comparison. You'd be playing ping pong with the server since you'd have to communicate the theme information with the server each time it changes. This pretty much means a page reload every time you change the theme (which is terrible for users). Passing the info in between page requests is also messy (especially for GET requests) -- unless you *store* the theme selection server-side, e.g. in a database.

Comment: Alternative solutions exist using cookies or you could make a POST request in the background to the flask server to update the selected theme (thereby preventing a page reload) -- but both of these alternatives also require JS.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it in my flask website is I store the user's choice of theme in database, specifically as a boolean in a "settings" table, which has a one-to-one relationship with "user" table.

This allows me to utilize Jinja and simply do something like this in the base.html template:

```
<html>
<head>
(...)

{% if current_user.settings.dark_theme %}
  <body class="dark_theme">
{% else %}
  <body>
{% endif %}

(...)
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can start setting up your css stylesheet using variables like so:

```
:root {
  --primary-color: #ffffff;
}

.dark_theme {
  --primary-color: #000000;
}
body {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```